# SFTP connection to a server using phpseclib and sha256

Tags: php, redhat, openssh, phpseclib, rsa-sha256

I have to connect to a SFTP server. I used first this code :

```
$Key = new RSA();
$Key->setPassword("password");
$Key->loadKey(file_get_contents('path_to_RSA_private_key'));
$sftp = new SFTP($IP_addr, $port_number);
if (!$sftp->login('username', $Key))
  echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s').' SFTP login failed to $IP_addr';
```

It worked well. I know phpseclib uses default sha1 and I would like to use sha256. So I tried with that code :

```
$Key = new RSA();
$Key->setHash('sha256');
$Key->setMGFHash('sha256');
$Key->setPassword("password");
$Key->loadKey(file_get_contents('path_to_RSA_private_key'));
$sftp = new SFTP($IP_addr, $port_number);
if (!$sftp->login('username', $Key))
  echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s').' SFTP login failed to $IP_addr';
```

But it doesn't work. I got that message on server :

```
error: key_verify: invalid format
```

If necessary, I can send debug logging on server side. This server uses default values for Ciphers, KexAlgorithms and MACs parameters.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I've made several tests by coding different values for **kexalgorithms** and **MAcs** on **sshd_config** of a server I want to connect to. And it work as I wanted it to work.

Thank you very much **Neubert** for your help and for the time you had to take to solve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [RFC4253](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#page-15):

> The "ssh-rsa" key format has the following specific encoding:
>
> ```
>   string    "ssh-rsa"
>   mpint     e
>   mpint     n
> ```
>
> Here the 'e' and 'n' parameters form the signature key blob.
>
> Signing and verifying using this key format is performed according
> to    the RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 scheme in [RFC3447] using the SHA-1 hash.

So your setting the hash to sha256 is probably breaking things. And the MGF Hash isn't even used since SSH doesn't support [PSS signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_signature_scheme) (which is what phpseclib defaults to).

That said, I do think you've hit on an area where phpseclib could use improvement - it [sets the signature scheme for SSH to PKCS1](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/2.0.11/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L2597) but it doesn't set the hash to sha1. It ought to.

Also, FWIW, [RFC8332](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8332) describes signing with SHA-256. But this signing still uses RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5. And just because an RFC exists doesn't mean your server supports it. You can check to see if it does by doing `print_r($ssh->getServerHostKeyAlgorithms())` and then seeing if `rsa-sha2-256` is in the list that's returned.

phpseclib doesn't currently support RFC8332 but I can look into adding support for that in the next few days and submitting a pull request...

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. I have access to that server and command "sshd -T" tells me that rsa-sha2-256 is in the list of returned values for hostkeyalgorithms parameter.

Comment: Does it mean that neither phpseclib nor libssh2 allow to connect to a SSH or a SFTP server from a php script otherwise than by using sha1 ?

Comment: @Schonke - I have no idea about libssh2 but for phpseclib, yah, that appears to be the case. But like I said, I'll try to make a pull request that implements the feature (I'll try to have this done this weekend). My pull request won't let you tell it sha1 / sha256, however. Instead, my pull request will automatically do sha256 if it's available and sha1 otherwise.

Comment: that's what I've understand. Very nice from you to act on this case. I hope it will help other people.

Comment: @Schonke - The latest git version of 2.0 should use sha256 / sha512 as previously discussed! The commit that did this: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/commit/b57976ec5ffc556f31036f713d5079ad59feb5d7 (the commit is in the 1.0 branch but it was merged and updated to work with the 2.0 and master branches as well)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it as soon as possible and let you know.

Comment: I have some problems to make it work. I'm on a RedHat 6 server using PHP 5.3.3. Some instructions don't work as `$config = []` on RSA.php. The previous phpseclib version was installed with yum and was titled 2.0.11-1.el6. I saw that phpseclib can work with PHP 5.3.3 so I've unzipped zip file into another folder and put the old autoload.php into that folder. What did I wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: @Schonke - sounds like you're using the master branch - not the 2.0 branch. To download the latest git version of the 2.0 branch use this link: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/archive/2.0.zip

Comment: I'm confused. It works much better. I have to try with sha256. Thanks.

Comment: @Schonke - the master branch only works on PHP 5.6+. The 2.0 branch works on PHP 5.3+. The 1.0 branch should work on any version of PHP5 and even PHP4 if you shim out a few functions.